# Can't get Chrome/Brave on Mac to render bold font on my stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, macos, google-chrome, brave

I'm trying to dial in my blog's stylesheet nicely, and I can't get bold to work on my mac on Chrome/Brave. It renders fine on Safari, and renders fine on Chrome/Brave on my Android device. This blog post uses bold a number of times, so it should work as a good example: https://blog.andrewparker.net/guide-and-the-importance-of-candidate-experience/

I thought maybe my font choice had poor bold options, so I tried a number of different fonts (Open Sans, IBM Plex Sans, and now Noto Sans), but all of them fail to render bold on Mac Chrome/Brave.

Any advance on what CSS to add or remove to get it rendering well on Mac Chrome/Safari?